# Why does JMockIt mock the getter X.getE() for class X in this snippet?

Tags: java, enums, getter, jmockit

NOTE: fully working code snippet follows at end of the question

I have a JMockIt test for a class `Service`  with two dependencies (`Factory` and `Consumer` in the snippet). The service internally asks the `Factory` dependency for an object of class `X`, then delivers that object to the `Consumer` dependency in this method:

`public void interact(int i, E e) {
            X v = f.create(i, e);
            c.consume(v);
        }`

In my test, I want to exercise the `Service.interact()` method and postulate through a strict expectation that the consumer shall receive a parameter value that satisfies specific properties. Now, since the parameter of type `X` is a POJO that doesn't implement equals(), I want to use its provided getter methods to perform my checks; `X` looks like this (full snippet follows at end of question):

`public static class X {
                private final int i;
                public final E e;
                // ... see below for full snippet
                public int getI() { return i; }
                public E getE() { return e; } // E is an enum`

So what I do is I try to check that the consumer receives a value with `X.getI() == 2` and `X.getE() == E.B` and I do this using both the `with(Delegate<X>)` and `withArgThat(Matcher<X>)` in my expectations block:

`new StrictExpectations() {{
     consumer.consume(withArgThat(new BaseMatcher() { // ...
// and
new StrictExpectations() {{
    consumer.consume(with(new Delegate() { // ...`

However, both checks fail because when they call `X.getE()` they receive something that is NOT the enumeration value `E.B`. The output of the unit test is:

```
-----------------------------------------
RUNNING CHECKS ON: i=2, e=B
Direct reference match.
Reference through getter mismatch!
Ordinal through getter reference: 0
Identity hashcode from getter reference: 1282788025
Identity hashcode of expected reference: 519569038
-----------------------------------------
RUNNING CHECKS ON: i=2, e=B
Direct reference match.
Reference through getter mismatch!
Ordinal through getter reference: 0
Identity hashcode from getter reference: 1911728085
Identity hashcode of expected reference: 519569038
```

First question is (the title of this post): why does JMockIt intervene with this getter in the first place? As far as I can tell, I have not asked it to mock class X so invocations to its getter methods should go into regular X bytecode, but apparently it does not; the ordinal of the returned enumeration value is zero, which seems like a default value for a mock. Is this expected behavior because I've missed/misunderstood something, or is it maybe a bug?

Second question is: assuming there is a valid reason for JMockIt's behavior, how can I achieve what I want and perform this kind of check on values that I can only obtain through X's getter methods? How can I fix this code to tell JMockIt to simply leave class `X` alone.

Here is the full snippet that will compile and run (also at http://pastebin.com/YRL7Pdzv), I have junit-4.12, hamcrest-core-1.3 and jmockit-1.14 in my classpath, and using Oracle JDK 1.7.0_51.

```
package demonstrate;

import mockit.Delegate;
import mockit.Mocked;
import mockit.NonStrictExpectations;
import mockit.StrictExpectations;

import org.hamcrest.BaseMatcher;
import org.hamcrest.Description;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

public class SomeTest {
    @Mocked
    Factory factory;
    @Mocked
    Consumer consumer;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        new NonStrictExpectations() {{
            factory.create(anyInt, (E) any);
            result = new Delegate() {
                @SuppressWarnings("unused")
                public X create(int i, E e) {
                    return new X(i, e);
                }
            };
        }};
    }

    @Test
    public void testWithMatcher() {
        System.err.println("-----------------------------------------");
        new StrictExpectations() {{
            consumer.consume(withArgThat(new BaseMatcher() {
                final int i = 2; final E e = E.B;
                @Override
                public boolean matches(Object item) {
                    return runChecks((X) item, i, e);
                }
                @Override
                public void describeTo(Description description) {
                    description.appendText("\"i=" + i + ", e=" + e.name() + "\"");
                }
            }));
        }};
        new Service(factory, consumer).interact(2, E.B);
    }

    @Test
    public void testWithDelegate() {
        System.err.println("-----------------------------------------");
        new StrictExpectations() {{
            consumer.consume(with(new Delegate() {
                @SuppressWarnings("unused")
                public boolean check(X x) {
                    return runChecks(x, 2, E.B);
                }
            }));
        }};
        new Service(factory, consumer).interact(2, E.B);
    }

    private static boolean runChecks(X actual, int i, E e) {
        System.err.println("RUNNING CHECKS ON: " + actual);
        if (actual.getI() != i) {
            System.err.println("Primitive int mismatch!");
            return false;
        }
        if (actual.e == e) {
            System.err.println("Direct reference match.");
        } else {
            System.err.println("Reference mismatch!");
            return false;
        }
        E otherE = actual.getE();
        if (otherE != e) {
            System.err.println("Reference through getter mismatch!");
            System.err.println("Ordinal through getter reference: "
                    + otherE.ordinal());
            System.err.println("Identity hashcode from getter reference: "
                    + System.identityHashCode(otherE));
            System.err.println("Identity hashcode of expected reference: "
                    + System.identityHashCode(e));
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public enum E {
        A, B
    }

    public static class X {
        private final int i;
        public final E e;

        public X(int i, E e) {
            this.i = i;
            this.e = e;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "i=" + i + ", e=" + e.name();
        }

        public int getI() {
            return i;
        }

        public E getE() {
            return e;
        }
    }

    public static class Factory {
        public X create(int i, E e) {
            return new X(i, e);
        }
    }

    public static class Consumer {
        public void consume(X arg) {
        }
    }

    public static class Service {
        private final Factory f;
        private final Consumer c;

        public Service(Factory f, Consumer c) {
            super();
            this.f = f;
            this.c = c;
        }

        public void interact(int i, E e) {
            X v = f.create(i, e);
            c.consume(v);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was told in the jmockit-users list that this is actually a bug.

The suggested workaround was to use `@Mocked(cascading = false) Factory factory;` and indeed it makes things work.